# How to detection collision on axis P with SAT

Tags: collision-detection, sfml

i have problem with rotation objects and separating axis theorem.
I can detect collision on axis X and Y but i can't add other axis.
Try to write that code:

```
//player vector
float lenght_box_p = odl(box_xy, box.getTransform().transformPoint(box.getPoint(0)));


//line vector
float lenght_line_p = odl(line_xy, line.getTransform().transformPoint(box.getPoint(0)));

// center vector
float lenght_center_p = odl(line_xy, box_xy);

// angle 
float angle = cos((rotations * M_PI) / 180);

//box projection
float projection_box_p = lenght_box_p * angle;

//line projection 
float projection_line_p = lenght_line_p * angle;

//center projection
float projection_center_p = lenght_center_p * angle;

float gap_p1 = lenght_center_p - projection_box_p - projection_line_p;

if (gap_p1 <0)
{
    return true;
}
```

I use two box 100 x 100, for now both boxes are oriented 59* from the horizontal axis.

That's all, thanks for help and sorry my english is no good...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good lib for Collision Detection, you should use this one, it can handle polygons : http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php